# minimum of array of floats in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minimum

How can I find minimum of array of floats in Python? The min() or array.min() did not work. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

z=np.array([[ -4.26141957e-01],
       [ -2.26582552e-01],
       [ -7.28807682e-03],
       [  2.72843324e-02],
       [ -5.59146620e-02],
       [ -2.06062340e-05],
       [  1.06954166e-09],
       [ -6.34170623e-01],
       [  5.07841198e-02],
       [ -1.89888605e-04]])

z_min=z.min()
```

which gives `z_min = -0.63417062312627426`. I am a Matlab user so this is confusing to me...

Comment: Yo what do you want to happen? That answer looks correct to me

Comment: Yeah... it's the right answer. Maybe you want `z[np.abs(z).argmin()]` the number with the least magnitude?

Comment: That looks correct. Are you forgetting to look at the negative powers of ten, which reduce the magnitude of the numbers?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answering! I am now officially completely blocked: how can -0.634 be smaller than -5.59146620e-02 (i.e. -0.0559)?

Comment: @Makaroni `-0.634 < -0.0559` is true, isn't it? Then `-0.634` is smaller — that's how `min()` works.

Comment: `-10 < -1` Right? Try it in Matlab, too. You'll get the same result. It's just how negative numbers work.

Comment: Maybe consider that `(-0.634) - (-0.0559) = -0.575`, a negative number. Therefore the first number is less than the second. Does that help?

Comment: To be clear, Matlab also returns -0.634...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.min()` returns the smallest number, or the "largest" negative number (if there are any). In this case the entry at index 7 is the minimum entry. It is `-6.34 * 10^-1` in [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), or `-0.634...` in long-hand.

**Printing all in long-hand**

Perhaps this will help:

```
print "\n".join(["%+0.10f" % e for e in z])

-0.4261419570
-0.2265825520
-0.0072880768
+0.0272843324
-0.0559146620
-0.0000206062
+0.0000000011
-0.6341706230
+0.0507841198
-0.0001898886
```

**To verify your answer**

The following will show that only one entry has this minimum value.

```
z <= z.min()

array([[False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
```

**One more example**

The number closest to zero can be found like this:

```
z[np.abs(z).argmin()]
```

Which is `1.06954166e-09` = `1.069 * 10^-09` in scientific notation or `0.000000000106...` in long-hand.

Comment: By the way, I guess you probably didn't need all this. I just figured it may help future readers.

Answer (score 5):

`z_min = -0.63417062312627426` looks like the right answer. Be careful about scientific notation.